# Does the term "family" include the person themselves?

Tags: word-usage

The Merriam-Webster Dictionary defines the term *family* as "a social group made up of parents and their children." So it's my understanding that this would include me, my parents and any siblings. However, some people say "you and your family" as if they're two separate entities. The examples I see the most often are "I wish you and your family all the best" and "deepest condolences to you and your family."

So does the term *family* include that person themselves? In other words, is the phrase "you and your family" redundant?

Comment: The sense is “you and (the rest of) your family.

Comment: Depends on context.

Comment: 'You and your family' would be used when speaking, or addressing a written message to, only one person from that family.

Comment: Then there’s “your whole family”...

Comment: This usage definitely depends on context, but the word "family" always depends on context: it may mean you plus your parents and your siblings; or you plus your spouse/partner and your children; or your extended family (including grandparents, aunts and uncles, and maybe even more distant relations); or your ancestors; or possibly something else. Hence it's always better to clarify.

Comment: 'Family' is ambiguous, a classic example of polysemy-with-hypernymy. 'Your family and you' etc force the non-inclusive sense and are often used and are often the better choice to disambiguate and/or to make more personal. 'We are a close-knit family' obviously forces the inclusive sense, but remains ill-defined, as @Stuart explains.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, family can specify exactly who and who it refers to. He's" family".
You and your family is not redundant. "Your family", or "the family that belongs to you."

When said in conversation, "your family is always welcome here" or "you and your family are always welcome here". By not including "you and", "your family" is referring to members of your family who are not present to hear it. My family is hosting our tenth annual holiday party in honor of the Singh family's arrival in the new world.

You and your family generalizes to "your family". Is your family going hiking this year? Without additional context, it's impossible to determine if "your family" and your family.

Family - FAMILiar to You

"Is he family?",
"No, never seen him before."

When used in writing, "your family" is almost always

Comment: This could do with an edit (if only to complete the final sentence). It's not all that clear what your position is with regard to the title question (_Does the term “family” include the person themselves?_) and the final few lines just confuse the issue. I'm a lot more familiar with some of my friends than I am with some members of my family.